# Regular expression group results

Tags: regex

For the following expressions

```
ABC<d,1><something,2,3>
Def<123,trial>
```

Is there a way to get the captured groups which corresponds to values within `<>`

While my attempt at validating such an expression is as follows `(\w+)(<.+>{0,})`. I wonder if I could have a regular expression which would return all the values between `<>` such that my groups would be `d,1`, `something,2,3` and so on

Comment: Do you mean like `\w+<([^>]+)>`

Comment: For your example, please show what the expected output would be.

Comment: You may not have an arbitrary number of groups in the match, but in .NET and PyPi Python regex you may easily grab *captures* if you use `(\w+)(?:<([^<>]+)>)+`, see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5cw%2b%29%28%3f%3a%3c%28%5b%5e%3c%3e%5d%2b%29%3e%29%2b&i=ABC%3cd%2c1%3e%3csomething%2c2%2c3%3e%0d%0aDef%3c123%2ctrial%3e)